# @vue-icons/feather dependency was not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got a simple Nuxt project that I'm working on, I installed [Vue Icons](https://vue-icons.github.io/) and tried to add a search icon to my component, but when compiling I get the following error:

```
This dependency was not found:                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                               
* @vue-icons/feather in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/SiteHeader.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&       
                                                                                                                                                                              
To install it, you can run: npm install --save @vue-icons/feather
```

But I already have it installed, both on my src, and functions folders (I'm hosting on firebase)

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.6.1",
  "@vue-icons/feather": "^1.0.19",
  "firebase": "^8.9.1",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
  "nuxt": "^2.0.0"
}
```

The import statement I'm using is the one directly copied from the website

```js
import { SearchIcon } from "@vue-icons/feather";
```

I some similar questions I read talked about [transpiling the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613136/how-can-i-transpile-a-dependency-in-node-modules-with-nuxt-2), but that did not seem to work, do I need to add 3rd party libraries to some other part of the nuxt.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll quote what is written in the documentation

> This project aims to regroup [...] common icons pack for Vue 3.

Nuxt2 is not compatible with Vue3.

If you want to use the exact same `vue-feather-icons` library, please use [this package](https://github.com/egoist/vue-feather-icons) for that purpose.

It should work as easily as

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ActivityIcon />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ActivityIcon } from 'vue-feather-icons'

export default {
  components: {
    ActivityIcon
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Otherwise, I can also recommend [unplugin-icons](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons) which will provide a LOT more and will be really flexible. And which also totally contains [the icons you're looking for](https://icones.js.org/collection/feather).

Awesome package, to not have to deal with all the annoying parts of looking up for a working packages on top of the other features.